# Counting dimensions in $\mathbb{C}P^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

"The space of lines in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ that meet two generic subspaces of complex dimension $i$ and $j$ fills out a subspace of dimension $i + j + 1$." One does one prove this, or at least intuitively understand why it is true? Does one pull back to $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ and translate this into a linear algebra problem?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: @KReiser Let's start with the easiest case, $i = j = 0.$ A subspace of dimension $0$ is a point in projective space, which is a complex line in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}.$ We are trying to count the dimension of the... subspace of complex planes that contains two generic complex lines?

Comment: @IAmFailure: A point in projective space is not a line in $\mathbb CP^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$; it is a line in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$.  But in any case, if you can't see that there is a unique line joining two distinct points in $\mathbb CP^n$, and that this line has dimension $1$, then you should practice more elementary projective geometry.

Comment: @tracing My bad, I did not mean to put an extra $P$ there...

Comment: The subspaces should not intersect. That's why you need $i+j \le n-1$. Then you can call them generic.

Comment: @tracing I can see it just fine in real projective space; for some reason the fact that it's complex makes it harder for me mentally. I suppose on the algebraic side it's the same proof, with every scalar replaced by a complex number...

Comment: @IAmFailure: If you try arguing "synthetically", as in my answer, then you can have the real picture in your head or on paper as intuition, but the arguments don't depend on what field of scalars you are using, and so are equally valid over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull back to $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, but you can also argue directly via geometry in $\mathbb CP^n$.

You have a line meeting each of the two subspaces (call them $V$ and $W$).  Unless it is contained in either one of them, it meets them each in exactly one point.
So the set of lines passing through a point of $V\setminus W$ and a point of $W\setminus V$ is dense in the set of all such lines.  Now the idea is that there
is an $i$-dimensional set of points on $V\setminus W$, and a $j$-dimensional set of points on $W\setminus V$, and for each such pair of points, there is a one dimensional set of points on the line joining them.  Adding up all the dimensions gives $i + j  + 1$ in total.

To make this precise, you have to think more carefully.  The most subtle point is that a point on the union of all the lines may lie on more than one line (in fact on a positive dimensional collection of lines) and hence may be over-counted.  If this happens for a general point on the union, then $i+j+1$ will be an over-count 
of the dimension.

You can see this in the case $n = 2$ and $i = j = 1$.

On the other hand, if $i + j < n,$ and $V$ and $W$ are generic, then $V \cap W = \emptyset$, and in fact you can see that the line joining $(v,w)$ and $(v',w')$
cannot meet unless $v = v'$ or $w = w'$ (and they meet just at $v$ or just at $w$,
unless $(v,w) = (v',w')$, in which case of course they are same line).  So in this case the dimension count is correct.

[To see this, suppose that these two lines meet in a point $x$ not lying on $V$
or $W$.  Firstly if either $v = v'$ or $w = w'$ then these two lines have two
points in common, and so they actually coincide (and $(v,w) = (v',w')$).
Otherwise we have $v \neq v'$ and $w\neq w'$.  Then the two lines span a $\mathbb CP^2$ in $\mathbb CP^n$, and any two lines in the projective plane meet. In particular, the line joining $v$ and $v'$ and the line joining $w$ and $w'$, both of which line in this plane, meet.  But the resulting point lies on $V \cap W$, 
which we assumed was empty.  Thus $x$ doesn't exist.]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, by the way. I'm just going to need a bit of time to process this. So, if I understand correctly, this isn't true at all as soon as $i + j \geq n?$

Comment: That's right (and you're welcome for the answer).